# No oil in the car

Tags: oil

Is it safe to put oil in a car that is leaking oil and then drive it to a auto shop down the street.
We try to get a tow but there no one avalible. The auto shop is down the street there is no oil in it. Been like that for few days

Comment: Depends on the leak and how far. If your oil goes below the pickup your engine will literally shred it self in seconds

Comment: The place is less then a mile and the leak is faster then a drip

Comment: That leak could turn into a bucket being poured out of the engine on the way there. There's no way i could speculate whether it will hold all the way across the internet. If you drive it there you are taking a risk to grenade your motor my friend. If you cant afford a tow truck then you definitely can't afford a new engine, have you tried to fix the leak? As i said it only take a few seconds for a motor to completely destroy itself from no oil.

Comment: How would you temperarally fix it to get to the shop

Comment: Just fix it permanently while your in there? I don't even know whats leaking on your car so i can't give you more advice than that.

Comment: So i found out the oil pan in one spot is rusted and thats it would there be a way to patch it up

Comment: The oil pan should be aluminium and not rust? is there a hole in your oil pan?

Comment: Yes there is a hole but its a rust made hole on my toyota hylander

Comment: And its On the oil pan

Comment: Hole in an oil pan sounds much more like mechanical damage ( by rocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the guys at the shop are more the right people to address this issue, especially since you need to make an appointment there and they should be near enough to make an assessment.

So just ask them how you are supposed to bring your car there with a massive oil leak (or broken oil pan?).

Perhaps they organize you a tow truck, tow it while on the road with a tow bar or patch it on site..

Comment: Thank you all for helping my car is back and running of i have any futher issue ill post more about it.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** as per your comments the oil pan or sump is made of steel, then one possible temporary repair is to screw a self-tapping screw or bolt into the hole with plenty of sealant.

This repair worked on an old truck once.  Then we took the sump off and welded it, but it lasted a couple of weeks in our case.

Comment: if it really is a rust hole(im doubtful) then all the material around the hole has already atrophied beyond the point of being tapped.

Comment: @DatsunZ1 well, read the last two lines, as in "it worked on an old truck..." If it does not work for you ....

Answer (score 0):

If it's less than a mile, no problem!  Add 1/2 quart extra oil to the crankcase before you begin.  Watch your dashboard for the "low oil" light and shut the car off immediately if it illuminates.

Comment: And if it's just the oil pan which is leaking at a dribble, clean it up really well and throw some duct tape over it. While it won't be a perfect fix, it will staunch the flow well enough to get you there without worrying.

Comment: The engine will be toast by the time the oil light comes on under load..

Comment: @DatsunZ1 It depends on whether the car's "oil light" indicates low oil pressure, or low oil quantity. Some cars' warning lights indicate oil quantity, not pressure.

Comment: @DatsunZ1 Under heavy load, you're probably right.  I have, however, had my oil light flicker while driving slowly, which was due to oil blockage.  No damage was done to the engine;  10k miles later the engine runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be just to push the car there. Relatively easy to do if you have few people to help. Don't even need to start the engine.

Consult your manual what is the proper way to do this, especially if you have automatic transmission.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how bad the leak is, however I would not recommend it. Not only is there a large risk of damage to your engine if it runs with too little oil in it, but there is also the environmental consideration - and in many countries you'd be opening yourself up for prosecution for causing pollution if it were known that you deliberately drove the car with a large, known oil leak